# selenium run slows down application performance drastically

Tags: performance, selenium, webserver

I run selenium tests for a web application we are developing.It eats up all memory at the server and server performance falls exponentially.Most of the times application gets completely down or gets very very slow.
2 hour of Automation script run is enough to permanently halt the server(so that other profiles hosted on the sever do not work).
What can be the possible reason behind it? and How to overcome it?
I use selenium RC for test execution.

Comment: If I have missed proper  Tagging, Please suggest right tags,so that my problem can be addressed better.

Comment: What are the dump files?

Comment: I dont know exactly because IT department handles such performance task.But it crosses the heap size they have allocated.

Comment: If anyone who has come across same problem in past,your help is heavily sought...Thanks'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to speak to the IT department, and ask them to analyse the logs to figure out what's different on this particular server. It's not really possible for anybody here to answer your question without a **lot** more data.